# Force verifying correct user on FB.login

Tags: facebook, authentication, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I'm using the JavaScript SDK with the FB.login function. Unfortunately [the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/) for this function is somewhat lacking in detail - only the 'scope' option is mentioned, even though [there are additional options](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/reauthentication/).

Currently, if a Facebook user is logged-in and has already previously approved my app, the **FB.login will automatically use the logged-in user and return without asking the user anything**. I'm searching for a way to make the FB.login dialog **ask the user to reconfirm it's his correct Facebook user** (similar to the `auth_type:'reauthenticate'` option but without actually forcing the user to re-enter his password).

It seems to  me a quite trivial feature I've already seen before in Facebook. **Is it supported?**

Comment: No, apart from re-authentication by asking for the password again there is no such functionality provided by FB directly. But you can always show the name/picture of the user the SDK logs in for you automatically, and place a “not you?” link next to it, that onclick calls the logout method and then ask for login again …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this point it seems that there is indeed no such functionality available in the Facebook API.

If you want the user to confirm his identity, it's either you ask him to re-enter his password by `auth_type:'reauthenticate'`, or implement a confirmation popup/dialog/etc yourself (as CBroe mentioned in his comment).